# Rewriting Erlang in F#

Tags: f#, erlang

I have found a [presentation](http://www.erlang-factory.com/upload/presentations/270/FSharp-ef.pdf) by Don Syme which shows that Erlang's

```
fac(0) -> 1
fac(N) -> N * fac(N-1).
```

is equivalent to F#'s

```
let rec fac = function
| 0 -> 1
| n -> n * fac (n-1)
```

But it looks like there is no way to use pattern matching for a different arity without losing type safety. E.g. one could use a list pattern matching, but then a type must be a common base type (such as `object`):

```
let concat = function
    | [x;y] -> x.ToString() + y.ToString()
    | [x] -> x.ToString()
```

Given that F# functions in modules do not support overloads, it looks like the only way to rewrite Erlang code into F# with static typing is to use static classes with method overloading instead of modules. Is there a better way to rewrite Erlang functions with different arity in F#?

In general, is it correct to say that Erlang's argument matching is closer to .NET's (including C#) method overloading rather than to F#'s pattern matching? Or there is no direct replacement between the two, e.g. there could be a function in Erlang with different arities + a guard:

```
max(x) -> x.
max(x,y) when x > y -> x.
max(x,y) -> y.
max(comparer, x, y) -> if comparer(x,y) > 0 -> x; true -> y end.
```

In the last case the arguments are of different types. How would you rewrite it in F#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve something close to overloading by rethinking the problem slightly. Instead of thinking about the *function* as the axis of variability, think of the input as the variable part. If you do that, you'll realise that you can [achieve the same with a discriminated union](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/10/21/replace-overloading-with-discriminated-unions).

Here's a more contrived example than the one in the linked article:

```
type MyArguments = One of int | Two of int * int

let foo = function
    | One x -> string x
    | Two (x, y) -> sprintf "%i%i" x y
```

Usage:

```
> foo (One 42);;
val it : string = "42"
> foo (Two (13, 37));;
val it : string = "1337"
```

Obviously, instead of defining such a 'stupid' type as the above `MyArguments`, you'd define a discriminated union that makes sense in the domain you're modelling.

Comment: That is nice, it also allows to use guards: `Two (x, y) when x > y`. But if some args are just optional, I am struggling to name the cases: e.g. Default, DefaultWithComparer, ... I need to name each combination of parameters, which feels somewhat weird.

Comment: @V.B. You can often handle defaults by creating default values of your input type. You don't have to make it a special case. As an example, if your function *always* needs a comparer, then make the comparer a mandatory field of the input type, but then supply a default value of that input type that has the default comparer, or alternative, supply a *function* that creates the input value with the default comparer.

Comment: Actually, instead of weakness I thought about in the previous comment, this is a kind of strength: message passing is central to Erlang, and one could think about each DU case as a name for a message. Each message has its own wire format, etc. Explicit naming of messages - even though verbose - could add readability at development/prototype stage. Then it could be replaced with blittable structs to avoid DU object allocations and serialization.